# How to set the volume of a USB soundcard?

Tags: usb, driver, linux-device-driver

I am a total newbie when it comes to programming or even talking directly to drivers. The thing I want to do is hooking up my Raspberry Pi with a 5.1 external USB-soundcard. I would really like to use the Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Surround Pro for that but Creative only provides Windows drivers. Which basically means I will have to write my own driver. While I assume that it will be quite easy to do the audio playback (I have done a fair amount of audio processing in my life) I don't have a clue how to set the USB card volume. I am honestly mostly irritated that the Sound Blaster has its own external volume control (which is the main reason for me to use it). Just applying a simple gain factor on the bit stream would be really easy.

My question is: Could it be that I would have to just set the system volume and that the volume control on the sound card just transfers values to the USB host which I then would have to make sense of? 
In case you do not know the Sound Blaster card, would that be the standard way of doing things?

Comment: Check out the *ALSA* project for support of your hardware.  http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Vendor-Creative_Labs

Comment: @sawdust Thanks for the advice. Basic functionality is established, let's see if I can get this working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same soundcard and am doing the same thing with the Raspberry Pi. The command you're looking for is:

```
$ alsamixer
```

This will open up a terminal-friendly GUI for modifying the audio output volume. You should see the Raspberry Pi onboard audio driver *BCM2835* and associated devices alongside your USB audio.

Alternatively, you can set the volume with a simple amixer command:

```
$ amixer -c 0 set Master 100%
```

which sets the volume of card 0 to 100%.

It's more than likely that the USB soundcard isn't being chosen as the default and is card 1, rather than card 0.

Check the following guides for further information on RasPi / USB Audio Setup:

- http://drewlustro.com/hi-fi-audio-via-airplay-on-raspberry-pi
- http://audioplastic.org/blog/2013/01/10/AP1/